# Number of intersections of two quadratic functions

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Is it correct, that the number of intersections of two polynomials with degree 2 is at most 2?

I would argue that the intersection points can be determined by using the quadratic formula, which provides at most 2 different values.

**Update:**
I consider two functions of form $f(x) = \frac{d}{ax^2+bx+c}$.

Comment: you mean the graphs of two such polynomials? Yes, that's true, and your reasoning ok. I'd do it this way: the difference is zero iff the graphs intersect, and the difference is also a polynomial of degree at most two.

Comment: What kind of polynomial? What do you mean by "intersection"? For example, the graphs of $x^2+y^2=0$ and $4x^2+\frac14y^2=0$ intersect four times. If you have a polynomial in $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ you can have infinitely many intersection points. Did you mean to deal only with graphs of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$ and the intersections of two such graphs?

Comment: Sorry for inaccuracy!
The considered functions have the form $f(x) = \frac{d}{ax^2 + bx + c}$, where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are constants.

Comment: @Yannic Those are not even polynomials...You should then change also the wording of your question. The mechanics of the problem though, are almost the same for the rational functions you want to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try $$ax^2+bx+c=dx^2+ex+f$$ and we get
$$(a-d)x^2+x(b-e)+(c-f)=0$$
If $a=d$ the the equation is linear, if not then we get by the quadratic formula
$$x_1=1/2\,{\frac {-b+e+\sqrt {-4\,ac+4\,af+{b}^{2}-2\,be+4\,dc-4\,df+{e}^{2
}}}{a-d}}
$$
$$x_2=-1/2\,{\frac {b-e+\sqrt {-4\,ac+4\,af+{b}^{2}-2\,be+4\,dc-4\,df+{e}^{2
}}}{a-d}}
$$
Also your case can reduced to this case:
$$\frac{d}{ax^2+bx+c}=\frac{e}{fx^2+gx+h}$$ is equivalent to
$$d(fx^2+gx+h)=e(ax^2+bx+c)$$ if $$ax^2+bx+c\ne 0$$ and $$fx^2+gx+h\neq 0$$

Comment: Note that this solution still works for two functions of the form $f(x)=\frac d{ax^2+bx+c}$